# Функционал к Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

Есть ли такая возможность, чтобы при наведении на объект(класс, структуру) курсором появлялся список его свойств и методов?

Comment: Не помню, наделён ли Resharper таким функционалом, но вы всегда можете написать своё расширение к VS)